# DirectShow samples and base classes relocated

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Since Windows SDK 8.1 the samples should be downloadable from Dev Center as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891). Anyway I was unable to find DirectShow base classes in Dev Center. Where those can be downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by installing Windows 7 with Windows SDK and extracting the samples.