# DirectShow (Stream.h) for Windows 10 Development

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10, directshow

I just noticed that streams.h is missing, while I was compiling DSVideoLib on my machine. 
A quick research pointed me to the Windows SDK.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407279(v=vs.85).aspx
Well after installing the windows sdk again, I still cannot find those files and folders in my windows sdk folder.

Does anybody have an idea where to get the DirectShow library on windows 10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Streams.h and and other BaseClasses directory files can be found in [Windows SDK 7.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), in \Samples\multimedia\directshow\baseclasses. [This](https://github.com/ganboing/sdk71examples/tree/master/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses) also looks like a good snapshot to grab.

See also (actually proves that taken out from Windows SDK 8.0, the code in question was never put back later):

- [Where are the DirectShow samples in the Windows 8 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941803/where-are-the-directshow-samples-in-the-windows-8-sdk)
- [Getting DirectShow Samples on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547892/getting-directshow-samples-on-windows-8)
- [DirectShow samples and base classes relocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380243/directshow-samples-and-base-classes-relocated)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657925/locations-of-windows-sdk-samples-in-windows-8-1

There is nothing bad in taking "old" DirectShow sample/base code because there has been so little changes over last 10+ years...