# Problems to get DirectShow BaseClasses

Tags: windows, directshow

I'm developing on Windows 10 64-bit and I need to add the references to `DirectShow`. I know it's not included anymore in `Windows 10 SDK` but it's still available in `Windows 7 SDK`. Well, I have a second machine with Windows 7 64-bit, with `.NET Framework`s 1.1, 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1 installed, as the program manager says.

I downloaded the SDK for x64 here:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/1/0/F10113F5-B750-4969-A255-274341AC6BCE/GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso

Launching the Setup.exe leads to the following warning:
[image]

but that (non-clickable) link just redirects to the Microsoft homepage.
I already have the Framework 4 installer - not RTM though.
I then tried to search for `RTM Framework 4` and I downloaded this file:

https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/download/details.aspx?id=36359

but it doesn't install with the following motivation:

> Installazione guidata dell'aggiornamento software KB2750147 non è applicabile oppure è bloccato da un'altra condizione sul computer.

That means the installation is not applicable or it is blocked from another condition on the machine.

Well, then I tried to go ahead with the installation of the `Windows 7 SDK`, confirming the default options. It ends immediately and the log reports a lot of similar errors:

> === Logging stopped: 21/03/2017  11:46:20 === MSI (s) (A0:88) [11:46:20:807]: Product: Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 (7.1) --
>   Installation completed successfully.
>
> MSI (s) (A0:88) [11:46:20:810]: Windows Installer: installazione del
>   prodotto completata. Nome prodotto: Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows
>   7 (7.1). Versione prodotto: 7.1.30514. Lingua prodotto: 1033.
>   Produttore: Microsoft Corporation. Installazione riuscita o stato di
>   errore: 0.
>
> === Logging started: 21/03/2017  11:46:22 === Action start 11:46:22: INSTALL. Action start 11:46:22:
>   DDSE_CA_Uninstall_InstallExecuteSequenceStarts_amd64. 03/21/17
>   11:46:22 DDSet_Status: LANGID: 1033 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_Entry:
>   ImmediateDispatch: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_InstallExecuteSequenceStarts
>   entry 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_Error: Patch Hooks: Missing required
>   property 'ProductFamily': Setup cannot continue. 03/21/17 11:46:22
>   DDSet_Warning: Setup failed while calling 'getDLLName'. System error:
>   0xb7 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_CARetVal: 0 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_Exit:
>   ImmediateDispatch: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_InstallExecuteSequenceStarts exit
>   Action ended 11:46:22:
>   DDSE_CA_Uninstall_InstallExecuteSequenceStarts_amd64. Return value 1.
>   Action start 11:46:22: FindRelatedProducts. Action ended 11:46:22:
>   FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0. Action start 11:46:22: AppSearch.
>   Action ended 11:46:22: AppSearch. Return value 0. Action start
>   11:46:22: LaunchConditions. Action ended 11:46:22: LaunchConditions.
>   Return value 1. Action start 11:46:22: ValidateProductID. Action ended
>   11:46:22: ValidateProductID. Return value 1. Action start 11:46:22:
>   DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostInitializePre_amd64. 03/21/17 11:46:22
>   DDSet_Status: LANGID: 1033 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_Entry:
>   ImmediateDispatch: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostInitializePre entry 03/21/17
>   11:46:22 DDSet_Error: Patch Hooks: Missing required property
>   'ProductFamily': Setup cannot continue. 03/21/17 11:46:22
>   DDSet_Warning: Setup failed while calling 'getDLLName'. System error:
>   0xb7 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_CARetVal: 0 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_Exit:
>   ImmediateDispatch: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostInitializePre exit Action
>   ended 11:46:22: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostInitializePre_amd64. Return
>   value 1. Action start 11:46:22: CostInitialize. Action ended 11:46:22:
>   CostInitialize. Return value 1. Action start 11:46:22:
>   DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostInitializePost_amd64. 03/21/17 11:46:22
>   DDSet_Status: LANGID: 1033 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_Entry:
>   ImmediateDispatch: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostInitializePost entry 03/21/17
>   11:46:22 DDSet_Error: Patch Hooks: Missing required property
>   'ProductFamily': Setup cannot continue. 03/21/17 11:46:22
>   DDSet_Warning: Setup failed while calling 'getDLLName'. System error:
>   0xb7 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_CARetVal: 0 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_Exit:
>   ImmediateDispatch: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostInitializePost exit Action
>   ended 11:46:22: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostInitializePost_amd64. Return
>   value 1. Action start 11:46:22: FileCost. Action ended 11:46:22:
>   FileCost. Return value 1. Action start 11:46:22:
>   DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostFinalizePre_amd64. 03/21/17 11:46:22
>   DDSet_Status: LANGID: 1033 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_Entry:
>   ImmediateDispatch: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostFinalizePre entry 03/21/17
>   11:46:22 DDSet_Error: Patch Hooks: Missing required property
>   'ProductFamily': Setup cannot continue. 03/21/17 11:46:22
>   DDSet_Warning: Setup failed while calling 'getDLLName'. System error:
>   0xb7 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_CARetVal: 0 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_Exit:
>   ImmediateDispatch: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostFinalizePre exit Action ended
>   11:46:22: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostFinalizePre_amd64. Return value 1.
>   Action start 11:46:22: CostFinalize. Action ended 11:46:22:
>   CostFinalize. Return value 1. Action start 11:46:22:
>   DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostFinalizePost_amd64. 03/21/17 11:46:22
>   DDSet_Status: LANGID: 1033 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_Entry:
>   ImmediateDispatch: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostFinalizePost entry 03/21/17
>   11:46:22 DDSet_Error: Patch Hooks: Missing required property
>   'ProductFamily': Setup cannot continue. 03/21/17 11:46:22
>   DDSet_Warning: Setup failed while calling 'getDLLName'. System error:
>   0xb7 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_CARetVal: 0 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_Exit:
>   ImmediateDispatch: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostFinalizePost exit Action
>   ended 11:46:22: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_CostFinalizePost_amd64. Return value
>   1. Action start 11:46:22: SetODBCFolders. Action ended 11:46:22: SetODBCFolders. Return value 0. Action start 11:46:22:
>   MigrateFeatureStates. Action ended 11:46:22: MigrateFeatureStates.
>   Return value 0. Action start 11:46:22:
>   DDSE_CA_Uninstall_InstallValidatePre_amd64. 03/21/17 11:46:22
>   DDSet_Status: LANGID: 1033 03/21/17 11:46:22 DDSet_Entry:
>   ImmediateDispatch: DDSE_CA_Uninstall_InstallValidatePre entry 03/21/17
>   11:46:22 DDSet_Error: Patch Hooks: Missing required property
>   'ProductFamily': Setup cannot continue. 03/21/17 11:46:22
>   DDSet_Warning: Setup failed while calling 'getDLLName'. System error:
>   0xb7

All this stuff only to get the library and include files for `DirectShow`!
Is this the only way to develop for that platform today?

Comment: Windows SDK 7.1 Samples is where you get the code from. [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next) is maintained DirectShow project (and a terrific must have tool too), which has BaseClasses also available on GitHub.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DirectShow (Stream.h) for Windows 10 Development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126103/directshow-stream-h-for-windows-10-development)

Answer (score 0):

I found here the content of the SDK I cannot install:

https://github.com/ganboing/sdk71examples/tree/master/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses